# PHP file storing on webhosting service?

Tags: php, iphone, hosting, nsmutablearray

I was wondering - is it possible to change files that are stored on some sort of 
webhosting service via PHP? I mean I have a URL say: "plist.atwebpages.com/action.php"  will it possible for this method to write a file onto the ftp server on the web hosting service?
e.g. http://www.batcave.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you need a [PHP FTP client library](http://www.radinks.net/ftp/php/).

Comment: But is it possible to implement this on a webhosting service? could you please elaborate, as I am not really familiar with PHP and such.
Thank you.

Comment: By using an FTP client library, your PHP code can access any FTP server in the just the same way that you can access it yourself using your FTP client.

Comment: If you can't set up a cron task to do the FTP, use a web page script which is called externally every once in a while...

Comment: That is, of course, given the fact that you have the username/password for that server on which the file resides on.

Comment: Could you refer me somewhere, as from what I understand so far it is possible even on a webhosting service if it has FTP server, all I need is the PHP code that can manipulate files according to received data. Am I correct?
Please give me a few links or write here.
Thanks.

Comment: Download the FTP client library I pointed you to. In there is sample PHP code (upload.php / upload.html) showing how to use that library to write a file to a remote FTP server.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it as soon as I can!